# How create my own login form Django

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication

I want to create a login form in Django, and I used this method:

```
def Login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']

            access = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if access is not None:
                if access.is_active:
                    login(request,access)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
                else:
                    return render_to_response('noactive.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            else:
                HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render_to_response('login.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Is there any way to create a form with a form created in forms.py and not with the django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm that Django provides to you?

Comment: class MyForm(AuthenticationForm) ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Django contrib form does a whole lot more

Comment: But if I want that my User get more information like "Date of birth" or "Blood type"? Something that django.contrib.auth.forms doesn´t gives you?

Comment: for that you need to create UserProfile, which extends from User, and create a modelForm on that

Answer (score 1):

So, I think you are confusing two different things: one is what you want to ask the user. The second is what you want to store in the database.

The first issue is implemented in [views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/) and [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/), while the latter is implemented in [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/), in particular [User profiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/).

Normally a form is associated with an action you want to perform to your database. Either insert new content or modify existing content (which includes user login).

So, my answer to your question is: you should try to read these 4 links I added. You have to understand the underlying idea of views as server responses to users requests, forms as tools to modify database with user input without damaging it, and models as data structures to store information in a structured way.

Hope this helps.